# Embedding the NEW google calendar

Tags: iframe, google-calendar-api, embed

Is there a way to embed the new Google Calendar view? (https://support.google.com/calendar/answer/7541906?hl=en)

I tried to use the link appearing in the calendar's settings - but the iframe loads the old view not the new one.

Comment: I think it is not yet supported in Calendar API and as you've stated, it is only supported for the Calendar app. I haven't tried it yet so what I can suggest is to redo the [tutorial](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/overview) in implementing the Google Calendar in your app. You may also file this as [feature request](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/support#missing_features).

Comment: I am here in 2020 wondering why the old Google Calendar is only supported for embeds. Hopefully we hear from it some day.